# View function throws an error with block.number

Tags: solidity, remix, error, solidity-0.8.x, view

Looking at https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/contracts.html#view-functions I understood the solidity `view` function can work with any function unless it mutate states, emit events or perform any other mutative operations.

Meanwhile I noticed the following does not work (at least in Remix). Returning the stored `blockNumber` or the `block.number` works but not returning their difference `blockNumber - block.number`.

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract ThrowsError {

    uint256 private blockNumber;

    constructor () {
        blockNumber = block.number;
    }

    function viewFunction() public view returns (uint256) {
        return blockNumber - block.number;
    }
}
```

Here's the error that Remix Javascript VM throws:

```
call to ThrowsError.viewFunction errored: VM error: revert.

revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

Are there more restrictions on `view` functions? Could it be a problem with the Javascript VM?

Answer (score 1):

> As blocks get mined the block.number will increase. The stored block
> number will be smaller than the current. Subtracting the two reverts
> because the result underflows (you can think of it like negative
> values). In solidity 0.8+ underflows are reverted by default.
>
> The error has nothing to do with visibility otherwise the compiler
> would have already warned you
>
> Hope that helps

From https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/s9blc7/how_to_use_the_view_function_with_blocknumber/htlsyox/

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not related to the `view` function. You assign `blockNumber` at constructor time and then at some later point call `viewFunction`, therefore `block.number` will always be greater (or if done in the deployment block equal) to `blockNumber`. So if you subtract `blockNumber - block.number` and type it as a `uint` then this will cause an underflow error.

All restrictions for `view` functions can be found in the official Solidity docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/contracts.html?highlight=view#view-functions